# Personal Finance & Money - Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

As our special thanks to you for *not only being extremely awesome*, but also being *extremely patient with us through the process of graduation*, I'd like to announce the immediate availability of some personalized items in our inventory just for this community.

If you're on the first or second page [of this list](https://money.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), you'll be receiving an email from me sometime this week offering you:

#### T-Shirts!

[image: Shirts]

#### Stickers!

[image: stickers]

#### PIGGIES!

[image: piggy banks]

If you're not on the list, don't worry - there will be plenty of opportunities for you to participate in small contests I'll be holding over the year, and we've got some reserve stock for conferences and events that you might want to attend to help promote the site.

As a *special thanks* for you all being *extremely patient* with us getting the design together, I'll be tossing in some extra things (pens, markers and other stuff with the SE logo that most people would find useful).

Thank you all again for putting together such a spectacular site, I'll be in touch with you soon!

Comment: Sweet.  I have been needing some stickers!

Comment: Excellent. I kept a spot free on my Macbook Air for precisely such a sticker :) Oh, BTW, I had bought (as in paid for) a StackExchange mug back when there was a shop to buy SE swag, but the handle broke late last year **:/** *<wink> <wink> <nudge> <nudge>*  :D

Comment: Responses have basically finished, I'll be sending this over to our warehouse at some point next week. Remember, allow 6 - 8 weeks for delivery (no, I'm not kidding, six to eight weeks is a _perfectly_ reasonab... oh I just give up.)

Comment: Always can use a tee.

Comment: Is it too late?  I just noticed the email now :o  I love piggies and Money SE!